# Exchange the limit with the expectation: why can I do it?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing, random-variables, expected-value

Hie everyone, I need a check on the following passage I found in a proof:

> Let $X$ be an **a.s. positive random variable** and let $h,t>0$.
>   Then $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^{+}} E[\frac{e^{-hX} - 1}{h}] = E[\lim_h \frac{e^{-hX} - 1}{h}]$$

Of course I need to apply a theorem such as Dominated Conv. theorem or Monotone convergence theorem, and I need a check on my reasoning.

---

If I look  at the graph  of the function (of $h$ ) $$f_X(h) = \frac{1-e^{-hX}}{h}$$ I can see that it converges monotonically to $0$ but the sequence is decreasing... so I can't apply the monotone 
convegence theorem in order to take the limit inside the expectation.

**BUT** If I look at the graph again, I can see that it's bounded by $X$ but $X$ is random and no one told me it's integrable. So I don't think I can apply dominated convergence.

I think I should apply monotone convergence, but the seuqence is not incresing... what can I do?

Comment: For all $X \geqslant 0$ we have $f_X'(h) \leqslant 0$, thus for every decreasing sequence $h_n \downarrow 0$ the sequence $$\frac{1 - e^{-h_nX}}{h_n}$$ is increasing. Monotone convergence works.

Comment: Oh right, my problem was that I was looking at the graph of $f_X(h)$ , but actually I had to look from right towards $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer By the way, I have another question (more general): usually in probability I need to exchange limit and expectation and the limit is taken w.r.t. a parameter such the $h$ in my question. 


If inside the expectation there's a random variable that does not depend on the parameter, do I have to take care of it when I apply the monotone convergence theorem?



I mean, the sequence of functions I have to look need to depend just on the index w.r.t. I take the limit, rigth?